# Convert days to years in R

Tags: r

I have dates in yyyy-mm-dd format. One column is interview dates, and the other is date_of_birth. I am trying to use interview_date - date_of_birth to calculate age, however it calculates it in days. I would like to convert this to years. I have tried looking this up and I cannot seem to find it, I apologize if this is a duplicate question.

Comment: can you divide days by 365.25 to get years?

Comment: ```lubridate::as.period(lubridate::interval("1988-01-01","2020-01-08"))```

Comment: @AmitKohli  please **DON'T** do that.  It's not correct,  and there's a reason that working libraries of date-time conversions are large and complicated.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft In practice, my method introduces almost no error. Try this: `(as.Date("2020-01-08") - as.Date("1988-01-01")) / 365.25`. It gives EXACTLY the same answer (well... 0.002 days difference) :) So within normal time scales, it's perfectly acceptable to divide days by 365.25. Give it a try! :)

Comment: @AmitKohli  your method introduces almost no error ... YET.   Sooner or later you will discover a couple dates which your method will add or subtract a day, or even a year from the correct difference.  **Don't roll your own date functions**

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can try the code below

```
df$age <- floor(as.numeric(do.call("-",rev(df)))/365.25)
```

or as @Allan Cameron stated in the comment

```
df$age <- as.numeric(df[[2]] - df[[1]]) %/% 365.25
```

which gives

```
> df
  date_of_birth interview_date age
1    1988-01-01     2020-01-08  32
2    1977-06-05     2019-12-15  42
```

**Dummy Data**

```
df <- structure(list(date_of_birth = structure(c(6574, 2712), class = "Date"), 
    interview_date = structure(c(18269, 18245), class = "Date")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,
-2L))
```

Comment: Or `as.numeric(df[[2]] - df[[1]]) %/% 365.25` ?

Comment: @AllanCameron Yes, sure. Thanks

Comment: Don't. Ever. Roll. Your. Own.  date-time functions.  Take the original character string,  use `as.Posix` or similar tools to get into actual date-time values, and then extract the delta year information you want.

Answer (score 1):

Set up some example dates:

```
t1 <- ymd("2018-12-12")
t2 <- ymd("2010-06-06")

difftime(t1, t2, units = "days")
```

difftime() will give you units up to weeks but not years.

I used lubridate to cast the dates as an interval, as.period to get the time between them as a period, then to get the number of years

```
interval(t2, t1) %>%
as.period() %>%
year()
```

or

```
year(as.period(interval(t2, t1)))
```

Without year, you get
"8y 6m 6d 0H 0M 0S"
and with year this gives 8 years difference as an integer.